# 3 dimension bar graph using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot3d

```
                1              2              3              4          5
a      0.1191610537 -0.08086102759 -0.17857896011 -0.30905164818 -0.1157044465
b      0.2672025804  0.06583418857 -0.09765886812 -0.07927341573  0.1997289846
c      0.2828267323  0.07980621918 -0.08597460186 -0.06583363052  0.1886023922
d      0.1880477739  0.20869361484  0.13106562750  0.12334558727  0.3943389846
e     -0.1117548300  0.07630696388 -0.07200355028  0.02621500555  0.1067601348
```

I have the following dataset and I am trying to put it into a graph as the following in ggplot2. I am running into errors when trying to plot it, I can paste my code if necessary. Anybody able to point me in the right direction?

[image]

EDIT: I get the following output running

```
library(plot3D)
hist3D(z = df, border="black")
```

[image]

Comment: yes please paste code as well as error you are getting

Comment: Well I was able to do it running;
`library(plot3D)
hist3D(z = df, border="black")`

But I get a different output